# Python Game | TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm working through a python book and was asked to create a tic-tac-toe game and understand the code which I do, relatively. Come time to run the program and I was given this weird error

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

with the full error being:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Tac Tac Toe Game revised.py", line 182, in <module>
     main()
   File "Tac Tac Toe Game revised.py", line 173, in main
     move = human_move(board, human)
   File "Tac Tac Toe Game revised.py", line 100, in human_move
     while move not in legal:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Here is the code it refers to in `line 173`

```
def main():
    display_instruction()
    computer,human = pieces()
    turn = X
    board = new_board()
    display_board(board)

   while not winner(board):
       if turn == human:
           move = human_move(board, human)
           board[move] == human
       else:
           move = computer_move(board,computer,human)
           board[move] == computer
       display_board(board)
       congrats_winner(the_winner,computer, human)
```

The error occurs in the following function:

```
def human_move(board,human):
'''Get human move'''
legal = legal_moves(board)
move = None
while move not in legal:
    move = ask_number('Where will you move? (0-8): ',0, NUM_SQUARES)
    if move not in legal:
        print ('\nThat square is already occupied, foolish human. Choose another.\n')
print('Fine...')
return move
```

I've tried changing `move = None` to `move = ' '` but that made no difference. any ideas?

As requested here's the function for `legal_moves`

```
def legal_moves(board):
'''Creates a legal list of moves'''
   moves = []
   for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
      if board[square] == EMPTY:
          moves.append(square)
```

Comment: what is `legal`? that is what is not iterable, not `move`. Clearly, `legal` is None but what should it be?

Comment: what does `legal_moves` return?

Comment: If you need additional help, please post the definition of `legal_moves`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `moves` list:

```
def legal_moves(board):
    '''Creates a legal list of moves'''
    moves = []
    for square in range(NUM_SQUARES):
        if board[square] == EMPTY:
            moves.append(square)
    return moves
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to return anything in legal_moves

An elegant solution would be to use 'yield square' instead of the moves list

Comment: I'm not sure what `yield square` is but hopefully I'll learn it. This answer was quite helpful but Henry's seemed more appropiate

Comment: The for-loop needs an iterable. A generator is an easy and efficient way to make one.

Comment: A generator creates the return values on the fly instead of storing them in a list (like your 'moves')  you can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156/1562285 or https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Answer (score -2):

your problem is you cant do a while loop on none variable you try to count nothing so this is the problem...

if you give a fidle of your code ill help you

Comment: what do you mean fiddle? Like pop in my entire code?

Comment: that is misleading - you cannot do a test for membership (i.e. use `in`) on `None`. `while None` is valid Python

Comment: what do you suggest it be re-written as?